# When does LASSO regression using coordinate descent fail to converge?

Tags: lasso, binary-data, algorithms, glmnet

I am fitting a large dataset using the glmnet package in R. My response is binomial and I have substituted the covariates with weight-of-evidence to make them all continuous and all on the same scale. I have been using this package for over two years without issue, yet with this setup, I have receive an error stating the model failed to converge for the 1st lambda value.

My question is, what properties of a data set can prevent LASSO using cyclical coordinate descent to fail to converge? Is there a way to improve the chances that LASSO will converge?

My colleague has mentioned duplicate records as possible culprits, yet that doesn't bear out in my analysis.

Comment: Perhaps it's the value of the 1st lambda.  Also, glmnet essentially uses a normal approximation to the binomial distribution, so I would look for if this approximation is causing problems - this can happen with very small and very large probabilities.  Are you able to track what glmnet is doing?  for example, can you print out the objective function as glmnet iterates?  or print the beta values for each iteration?

Comment: Constant columns can be a problem as well... Or this can happen if the tolerance / maxiter criterions are badly set.